# Removing response from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently getting a response from an AJAX call, the response is added to the inner HTML of an ID, is it possible to create a function which only removes this response?

```
function get_chat(name){
 var name = name;
 $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'getchat.php',
   data: {
   name_id:name
 },
 success: function (response) {
 messenger.innerHTML = response;}
 });
}
```

Comment: *"...which only removes this response?"* I'm not sure what you mean by that...? My first thought is `function clear_chat() { messenger.innerHTML = ""; }` My second thought, if you mean "only remove it if it's the response", is to declare `var clear_chat;` and then in the success handler: `clear_chat = function() { if (messenger.innerHTML === response) { messenger.innerHTML = ""; } };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your setting the `innerHTML` attribute.  In that case, you just have to reset it like this:

```
function get_chat(name){
 var name = name;
 $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'getchat.php',
   data: {
   name_id:name
 },
 success: function (response) {
 messenger.innerHTML = response;}
 });
}

function remove_chat() {
    messenger.innerHTML = "";
}
```